# Apostrophe not preceded by \\

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a string resource value like this:

```
<string name="you_sure">Are you sure you want to do this?\n(It can't be recovered.)</string>
```

When build my android project, I constantly get the error:

```
Error:(377) Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in Are you sure you want to do this?\n(It can't be recovered.))
```

Why?

Comment: Because the apostrophe isn't preceded by `\\`

Comment: how to, could you please be more explicit ? `"\n`?

Comment: It's not the newline, it's the apostrophe that **must** be escaped. So `can't` must be `can\'t`.

Comment: All commenters, be aware that the backslash character breaks the Markdown formatting when used improperly.

Comment: Why downvote? For I don't know something you know? ....ok, nice downvoting.

Comment: @Leem.fin I guess that is because of the error message is kind of self-explanatory. When it says "Apostrophe not preceded by \", then you must do precede it with a backslash it order to fix it.

Comment: @MCEmperor, but I don't fully understand that message, that's why I come to StackOverflow. P.S. I am not a english native speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have an apostrophe (the `'` in "can't"), and those need to be escaped as `\'`. The same holds true for quotes (`\"`).

Comment: do you mean replace `\n` to `\`n` ??? Are you sure? I need a line break that's why I use `\n`

Comment: You should add a link to the Android docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling.

Comment: @Leem.fin Nobody said anything about `\n`.

Comment: OK, now I see, but there are backslashes in my string, the first glance at the answer makes me think about the new line characters, it would be nice if the answer could be more direct & explict. But I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the [manual](http://Https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

Both

> This\'ll work

and

> "This'll work"

are correct

You need not to escape '\n'

Comment: Oh gosh, I ve not seen that somebody answered before me.